# Paypal recurring payment using express checkout not returning invoice after sucessfully payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to setup PayPal recurring payments using express checkout in ruby on rails. I have integrated first time recurring payment using paypal so sorry for silly question if it is.

I am using "SetExpressCheckout" method to passing the values to the paypal.

I am passing this data into the redirection url like this.

```
data = 'USER='+Settings.paypal_user+'&PWD='+Settings.paypal_password+'&SIGNATURE='+Settings.paypal_signature+'&VERSION=86.0&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0='+description+'&cancelUrl='+Settings.paypal_profile_return_url+'&returnUrl='+returnUrl+'&PROFILESTARTDATE='+Time.now().to_s+'&BILLINGPERIOD=Day&AMT='+order.total_price.to_s+'&CURRENCYCODE=CAD'+'&PAYMENTREQUEST_n_INVNUM='+invoice
```

This is my code which redirect to the paypal.

```
uri = URI.parse('https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
request.body = data
response = http.request(request)
response_body = URI.decode(response.body)
if response_body.split("&")[0].include?("TOKEN")
   token = response_body.split("&")[0]
   token.slice!('TOKEN=')
   redirect_to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscrcmd=_express-checkout&token=#{token}"
   return
end
```

Everything working fine. Payment can be done. I have set IPN url for redirection. After sucessfully payment IPN redirection url with notifacation controller call and that redirection url come back to my application in notification controller. I want to get invoice number into the notifaction controller as a params from WEBHOOK request.
WEBHOOK request can't give me invoice number as a paramater.

What is missing don't know  so please help me out.

This is the webhook request after successfully payment.

```
webhook request:::::: {"mc_gross"=>"191.40", "outstanding_balance"=>"0.00", "period_type"=>" Regular",  "next_payment_date"=>"03:00:00 Sep 26, 2017 PDT", "protection_eligibility"=>"Eligible", "payment_cycle"=>"every 7 Days", "address_status"=>"confirmed", "tax"=>"0.00", "payer_id"=>"XYZ", "address_street"=>"XYZ", "payment_date"=>"04:21:08 Sep 20, 2017 PDT", "payment_status"=>"Completed", "product_name"=>"Subscription - XYZ", "charset"=>"windows-1252", "recurring_payment_id"=>"I-ACEDHN4CW1F0E", "address_zip"=>"123456", "first_name"=>"sanjay", "mc_fee"=>"5.85", "address_country_code"=>"US", "address_name"=>"xyz", "notify_version"=>"3.8", "amount_per_cycle"=>"191.40", "payer_status"=>"verified", "currency_code"=>"CAD", "business"=>"ankita.koitiya-facilitator@bacancytechnology.com", "address_country"=>"United States", "address_city"=>"xyz", "verify_sign"=>"cas52InFHk3cJ5j80u2Udq.A26J4AqTyZhG.AwL7vRFZd2nF9yBvISOP", "payer_email"=>"xyz@gmail.com", "initial_payment_amount"=>"0.00", "profile_status"=>"Active", "amount"=>"191.40", "txn_id"=>"3B470367SX972320F", "payment_type"=>"instant", "last_name"=>"vyas", "address_state"=>"CA", "receiver_email"=>"sandboxtestaccount@gmail.com", "payment_fee"=>"", "receiver_id"=>"NW67DH9TEACW6", "txn_type"=>"recurring_payment", "mc_currency"=>"CAD", "residence_country"=>"US", "test_ipn"=>"1", "transaction_subject"=>"Subscription - xyz", "payment_gross"=>"", "shipping"=>"0.00", "product_type"=>"1", "time_created"=>"04:16:21 Sep 20, 2017 PDT", "ipn_track_id"=>"a0e1f9e94e7c2", "controller"=>"notifications", "action"=>"create"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the response you are getting from Paypal, can you paste that ?

Comment: I have updated please check it in question.
That is the response of webhook after successfully payment.

Comment: Do you see an invoice number from your dashboard on paypal , i don't think there's one for recurring payments .

Comment: You can give this a try - https://github.com/paypal/invoice-sdk-ruby

Comment: Thank you, I will try this one.

Comment: No, I am showing invoice number on dashboard. Why it's not creating invoice number i don't know. Payment can be done succesfully.